# Get page (nested) level scrapy on each page(url, request) in spider

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

Subj.I want to get page (nested) level in scrapy on each page(url, request) in spider, is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time we found the solution - response.meta['depth']

Answer (score 0):

Would some [verbose stats about depth](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#depth-stats-verbose) work for you?

Comment: No, I wanted this information for usage in each item, but we found the solution - response.meta['depth'].

Comment: good stuff. you might add and accept an answer to that effect for the benefit of those who follow!